# Neural Network not learning

Tags: neural-network

I am trying to build a simple feedfoward neural network with three layers for an autonomous car control. The network takes image frame inputs from a live video stream,  and gives steering value as output ranging from 0 to 1000. The inner layer has 38400 units  and output layer 1000 units. My training dataset is 2592 large and the problem I am having is finding the right number of neurons in the hidden layer. I have followed some rules of thumb that I found online , like

1. The number of neurons in the hidden layer should be between the input and output layer
2. The training dataset should be at least twice as large as the number of neurons in the hidden layer.

That gave me a boundary of 1000 and 1296 neurons. I’ve tried different architectures of networks within this range but the best accuracy I’ve got is not more than 2%,  with a single  epoch. I don’t know what’s going wrong. What should I do ?

I will appreciate any help I get.

Comment: Do you input the video? or its frames as image?

Comment: It sounds unlikely that a 3-layer feedforward NN could work in your problem setting, given that you are working with a live video stream. It would also be helpful if you clarify what are the "decisions" your algorithm is trying to make.

Comment: Do you strictly need 1000 outputs? What do the outputs represent? Are they true separate classes, or do they represent something with some structure - e.g. if they represent different degrees of steering, then you lose some inherent knowledge by modelling that as entirely different classes.

Comment: @ Niel Slater- Yes, they represent different degrees of steering.

Comment: @Biram Then you should model your problem as a regression problem instead of a classification problem.

Comment: @user12075 I am treating the output as discrete classes not continuous . I am new to machine learning so I opted to use the opencv MLP module which provides an easy interface for modeling problems

Comment: @Biram I see you are *new to machine learning*. Otherwise you would not have modeled a continuous variable *as discrete classes*, which is an obvious mistake in ML.

Comment: @Biram: I agree with user12075. One core problem you have is due to modelling what should be a continuous variable that many discrete steps. That's because assessing the error in a continuous problem you usually care about how *close* you are to the correct answers, not whether you are categorically correct.